# Flask Pagination with Sqlalchemy and JInja2 . Error : werkzeug.routing.BuildError werkzeug.routing.BuildError: ('users', {'page': 2}, None)

Tags: flask, pagination, sqlalchemy, jinja2

Hi I want to build a pagination with jinja2 -

Please help me

```
@app.route('/users')
def all_users():
   users_list = User.query.paginate(1, per_page=2,error_out=False)
   if users_list.has_next:
       next_url = url_for('users', page=users_list.next_num)
   if users_list.has_prev :
       prev_url = url_for('users', page=users_list.prev_num)
   return render_template("users.html",  users=users_list.items,
                          next_url=next_url, prev_url=prev_url)
```

<------ users.html ----->

```
{% for user in users %}
        <table>
        <tr valign="top">
            <td>{{ user.id }}</td>

            <td>{{ user.user_fname }}</td>

        </tr>
    </table>
{% endfor %}

    {% if prev_url %}
    <a href="{{ prev_url }}">Newer posts</a>
    {% endif %}

    {% if next_url %}
    <a href="{{ next_url }}">Older posts</a>
    {% endif %}
```

Every time I got the error like this -

werkzeug.routing.BuildError
werkzeug.routing.BuildError: ('users', {'page': 2}, None)

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should fix it like this `url_for(".users", page=users_list.next_num)`,
Be sure to define the function `def users(page)`